# Installing Windows 2003 over remote DRAC 4

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, remote, kvm-virtualization, drac

I'm trying to install windows 2003 over a DRAC 4 console session by using a ISO file.

But it keeps freezing during the GUI installation then when login back Windows Setup says some files not found and setup won't continue.

What's the best approach to install Windows 2003 over a DRAC 4 console session?

Answer (score 2):

are you installing over LAN or WAN? in wAN environments, because of the slow link, you might experience problems.

also, since it's a dell server, use the SMTD/SBUU ISO to ready the server for windows installation instead of booting with a windows ISO directly

Comment: It's over the internet. I don't have physical access, I'm not sure what is a "SMTD/SBUU ISO" ?

Comment: I've just found out Dell OpenManage and looking into it

Comment: I've seen corrupt installations many times, when done over the internet like this. DRACs and other avocent clones are designed to be used over a LAN link not over internet

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](http://pardini.net/blog/2008/07/09/dell-drac5-virtual-media-cdrom-breaks-os-installationboot-up-problems-and-fix/) a few years ago about this, and although it refers to DRAC5, it should help you.